# Making an automatic reply?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I want to make an app which in user1 sends a message to user2 with some specific text. user2 automatically sends the location by sms to user1 but user 2 should not be informed.
The below BroadcastReceiver when recieves a text displays "Got It".. How do i make an automatic reply when the message "UPDATE" is received

IncomingSMSReciever.java

```
public class  IncomingSMSReceiver extends  BroadcastReceiver{
private static final String SMS_RECEIVED =
        "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context _context, Intent _intent) {

    if (_intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
        Bundle bundle = _intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {


            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++)
                messages[i] = SmsMessage
                        .createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            for (SmsMessage message : messages) {
                String strPhoneNo = message.getOriginatingAddress();
                String msg = message.getMessageBody();

                if (msg.startsWith("UPDATE"))
                {

                    Toast.makeText(_context, "Whats up!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // this stops notifications to others
                    this.abortBroadcast();
                    // do what you want

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

SvrSmsListener.java

```
public class SrvSmsListener extends Service 
{
IncomingSMSReceiver SMSReceiver=new IncomingSMSReceiver();
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}
public void onCreate() {
final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(SMS_RECEIVED);

BroadcastReceiver receiver = SMSReceiver;
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
if (SMSReceiver != null)
{
    unregisterReceiver(SMSReceiver);
}
}
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Comment: Do you want to automatically send an sms message from the user's device to an external number without the user knowing about it ?

Comment: yes!! But the reply should be to the same no from where it got the text.. to be more specific.. if i want to locate you.. i will send you a text message and your phone will reply me with your latitudes and longitudes without you knowing about it..

Comment: So basically you are trying locate a device/person without the person knowing it that too with a SMS ? What is this going to be used for ?

Comment: Hmmm.Unless the user knows that an SMS is being sent from their device, any app will fall flat for violating user's privacy. And moreover, if the the user receives and SMS, they will definitely know and any message sent will be stored on the internal sms data store.

Comment: Dats why i said its for commercial purposes...

Answer (score 0):

When you detect that the incoming message starts with the WORD "UPDATE", you can invoke the SmsManager and use the sendTextMesage to send a text message to a specified number. You seem to have all the code ready except the sending piece, Is there an issue you are facing.

Comment: Actually I am facing the problem with the code part... If you cam help me with dat...